# What do you prefer for showing your local rails projects to friends?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost

I develop my rails applications at my local machine.

How can I easily show friends of mine the current state of the project?
I have heard of tunnlr, but I am a poor student that looks for a free solution:-)

Best regards

Comment: Do you mean the source or the output?

Answer (score 9):

[Heroku](http://heroku.com).

Deploying a free application is as simple as:

```
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
```

And you can scale up from there if you ever need to obviously as well.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku ( http://heroku.com/ ) is great for quickly deploying a rails app (using git), and a developer account is free.

Answer (score 1):

Give them your IP address?

Comment: Depending on how the machine is connected to the internet, the IP address may be dynamic.

Comment: And firewalled and you probably don't want to show everyone so you may also want to add some authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I demo projects with [crossloop](http://www.crossloop.com/) from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a small Linux VmWare with rails + webserver.
Then use capistrano or any other tool to push changes to it.
Copy VM with VmWare Player to a flash drive, give it to a friend and you are done ;-)

Of course it works for "local" friends.

In fact there are <100Mb linux distros so you can upload it to rapishare or any other free file hostings.

Answer (score 1):

Free hosting service for rails is  now provided @ http://herokugarden.com

Step 1: Create an account in herokugarden.com

Step 2 : Create a new rails application

Step 3 : Edit your project settings and export your project and migrate your migration files

Step 4 . Url of your application will be "http://projectName.herokugarden.com "

Step 5 : Share this link  to show your local rails projects to your friends

Good luck !!!

Answer (score 1):

I just used http://localtunnel.com , which looks like it's free (didn't even have to sign up for anything). Also heard of http://showoff.io , which seems to have a free option.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/plans has a free plan - its great if you use GIT

Answer (score 0):

[Forwardhq.com](http://forwardhq.com) is extremely convenient and easy to use.